# In Mario Party 4, what are the odds of the lottery house?

Tags: mario-party-4

In Mario Party 4, there's a lottery house where you can win an item, 30 or 100 coins.

What are the odds to win a prize in the lottery house?

[image]

Comment: I did some research and the only information I could find were peoples different "tricks" to try and get the 100 coin prize consistently. I think for this to be definitively answered, many tests would have to be done by players. Sadly, I could find no such tests having been done. :/

Comment: These people seem to have a few things to say about it

https://www.marioboards.com/index.php?topic=24101.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This video investigates the lottery shop. It's all in commentary rather than text unfortunately.

For the scratch game, out of the 12 cards, there is 1 item, 1 thirty-coin prize, and 1 hundred-coin prize. This means you'll win something 25% of the time, and the chance of winning any prize in particular is 8.33%. Pretty good odds actually.

For the ball game, nothing is in the player's control. The video did 100 tests and got:

- 66% lose
- 22% item
- 10% thirty coins
- 2% hundred coins

...which is a higher chance of winning something than the scratch game, but an unequal chance of what you do win. (I'm guessing the true probabilities are 20%, 10%, 1%, but who knows.)

The game picked and its results are determined when you hit the dice block to start your turn.